# How to download all dependencies with vgo and a given go.mod?

Tags: docker, go, vgo

I'm working on a go project, using vgo, with a Dockerfile, and I'd like docker to cache the dependencies of the project such that it has two properties:

1. If the `go.mod` file changes, the dependencies will be re-downloaded
2. If I change a file in the package, but do not change `go.mod`, the dependencies will not be re-downloaded.

Right now, I do:

```
...
RUN go get -u golang.org/x/vgo
COPY . /go/src/whatever
RUN vgo install
...
```

But if you change a go file, the dockerfile will have to be rebuilt from the `COPY` layer onwards.

What I'd like, in short, is to do:

```
...
RUN go get -u golang.org/x/vgo
COPY go.mod /go/src/whatever
RUN vgo install_dependencies
COPY . /go/src/whatever
RUN vgo install
...
```

That way, if I change `go.mod`, all the dependencies will be downloaded and rebuilt, but otherwise, we can proceed right to building the binary.

I can see a couple of ways to get behavior like this, but all of them have drawbacks:

1. I could copy `$GOPATH/src/mod` into the docker container, but that's going to have lots of files I don't need
2. I could `vgo mod -vendor` before I build the docker container, and copy the vendor directory, but that relies on the developer to remember to run `vgo mod -vendor` every time that `go.mod` changes, otherwise the app won't build and they'll have to run `vgo mod -vendor` before retrying the docker build.

Can you think of a way for me to get behavior like my imaginary `vgo install_dependencies`? Am I missing a vgo trick to do so?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why can't you run `vgo mod -vendor` as a Dockerfile command?

Comment: @TimCooper for that to work I think I need the whole directory copied to the docker image, which means it’ll re-run every time I modify a go file, even if it doesn’t change any imports

Comment: @TimCooper verified, if you try it with only a go.mod file in a directory you get `vgo: no dependencies to vendor`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

tl;dr: In current go master and in future go releases, `go mod download` will do this job. For now you need a hack.

On the gophers slack, I was referred to this issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26610 where I learned that this would do more or less what I want (assuming here that you're using go version 1.11beta3):

```
# Populate the module cache based on the go.{mod,sum} files.
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go list -e $(go list -f '{{.Path}}' -m all)
```

Later in the thread, Russ Cox implements `go mod download`, which will be available in the next release of `go`, allowing me to remove the silly `go list` hack above.

update: `go mod download` is now widely available and you should use it on go 1.12 and later

Answer (score 1):

I had an exact same problem, wanted to make Docker caching more accurate.

So I've just written my own tool for that: https://github.com/gladkikhartem/gomodget

Now my docker-in-docker pipelines are just 10 seconds and the docker build log looks like this:

```
Step 4/15 : RUN go get -u golang.org/x/vgo
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 12c672a07a16
Step 5/15 : RUN go get github.com/gladkikhartem/gomodget
 ---> Using cache
 ---> acc70fea0edc
Step 7/15 : COPY go.mod .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 41bae1ca7428
Step 8/15 : RUN gomodget
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 758100f7dde2
Step 9/15 : COPY . .
 ---> cc833c5bc810
Step 10/15 : RUN vgo build -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o /bin/app
```

Comment: Very cool! I think you'll be excited about `go mod download`, which should come out in the next release.